# How to create my own commands in CLI

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, command-line-interface

So Im creating my own CLI just to see if I can but Im struggling with one problem.
I cant create my own commands with parameters for example how would you go so when your java program is running and you type in the console /write Hello World and the console have to output Hello World? I can give you the code but its not much its just a loop and when the user types /stop it escapes the loop. I searched in google but cant find similar problem to mine! Just give me a simple example of that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to write conditions just like you did for `/stop`. Writing a CLI seems like it should be simple, but there are many cases to consider.

Comment: For example, `String line="/write Hello World"; String[] tokens = line.split(" ")` -- now `tokens[]` contains [ "/write", "Hello", "World"]. There are lots of ways of doing this, e.g. `StringTokenizer`. Explore the Java class library. Real command lines have more work to do, e.g. dealing with quotes. These are called "parsers" and are the kind of thing you might learn to write in a degree level CS class.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually at the beginning i really though that writing a CLI wont be complicated. But it seems that is even harder than writing a GUI.